# Misaligned math expression inside subfig

Tags: amsmath, subfloats

I am trying to get the matrix to align with the figures,  but I can't figure out how to do it. The matrix always appears much lower than the figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage{amsmath}  % draw matrices
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Undirected graph.]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic1.png}
        \label{fig:gr_undirected}
    }   
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency list.]{        
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic2.png}
        \label{fig:gr_undirected_ll}
    }
    \hfill
    \large  
    \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency matrix]{       
       $\begin{bmatrix}
       0 & 1 & 0 \\
       1 & 0 & 1 \\
       0 & 1 & 0 
     \end{bmatrix}$
        \label{fig:gr_undirected_am}
    }   
    \caption{An undirected graph and its representations.}
    \label{fig:gr_undirected_representation}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The baseline for the images (not rotated) is the bottom of the image. But the matrix is vertically centered around the math axis; the base line is not at the bottom, but higher, a little lower than the middle.

The math can be shifted by the depth using `\raisebox{\depth}{...}`. The example also removes some unwanted spaces that are added by line ends.

The first and second captions have the letter `g` with a descender, which is not present in the first line of the third caption. The example adds a phantom `g` to get the correct alignment of the baseline of the first lines of the three captions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage{amsmath}  % draw matrices
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Undirected graph.]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic1.png}%
        \label{fig:gr_undirected}%
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency list.]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic2.png}%
        \label{fig:gr_undirected_ll}%
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[%
      \leavevmode % start paragraph mode
      \protect\vphantom{g}% add space of descender in first line
      \protect\hspace{0pt}% allow hyphenation of next word
      Un\-di\-rect\-ed graph ad\-ja\-cen\-cy matrix%
    ]{%
       \raisebox{\depth}{%
         \large
         $\begin{bmatrix}
         0 & 1 & 0 \\
         1 & 0 & 1 \\
         0 & 1 & 0
         \end{bmatrix}$%
       }%
       \label{fig:gr_undirected_am}%
    }
    \caption{An undirected graph and its representations.}
    \label{fig:gr_undirected_representation}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Variation with centered matrix

- The matrix is horizontally centered in the space of `.3\textwidth`.
- Assuming that the image heights are equal, the height of the second image is measured and the matrix is vertically centered in this space by using another
  `\raisebox`. The nested `\raisebox` can be merged, but the math would be more complicate to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\usepackage{amsmath}  % draw matrices
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Undirected graph.]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic1.png}%
        \label{fig:gr_undirected}%
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency list.]{%
        \sbox0{%
          \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic2.png}%
        }%
        \xdef\GlobalImageHeight{\the\ht0}%
        \usebox{0}%
        \label{fig:gr_undirected_ll}%
    }
    \hfill
    \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency matrix]{%
        \hbox to 0.3\linewidth{%
            \hfill
            \raisebox{.5\dimexpr\GlobalImageHeight-\height}{%
                \raisebox{\depth}{%
                    \large
                    $\begin{bmatrix}
                    0 & 1 & 0 \\
                    1 & 0 & 1 \\
                    0 & 1 & 0
                    \end{bmatrix}$%
                }%
            }%
            \hfill
        }%
        \label{fig:gr_undirected_am}%
    }
    \caption{An undirected graph and its representations.}
    \label{fig:gr_undirected_representation}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you very much. In my testing the \raisebox command can move the matrix higher. I should maybe modify the original question, but is there a way to actually center the matrix vertically? Or specify it's size so that it too takes up 0.3/textwidth?

Comment: oh, please make that last caption ragged right, to get rid of the horrid spacing!

Comment: @barbarabeeton The spacing should now be better by using package `microtype` and hyphenation hints.

Comment: @kristoh The updated answer adds a variation that vertically centers the matrix using the height of the second image and horizontally centers it using the space of `.3\textwidth`.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend switching to `subcaption` which makes things rather easier in many respects than `subfig`. (I know as I recently switched for just this reason.)

For example, `\subcaptionbox` can be used to automatically align the baselines of things and to align their captions, even if their captions have different heights and/or depths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}% don't use h as the sole specifier
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{Undirected graph.\label{fig:gr_undirected}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic1}}
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{Undirected graph adjacency list.\label{fig:gr_undirected_ll}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic2}}
    \hfill
    \subcaptionbox{Undirected graph adjacency matrix\label{fig:gr_undirected_am}}
    {\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}
      \large
      \[\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0
      \end{bmatrix}\]
    \end{minipage}}
    \caption{An undirected graph and its representations.}
    \label{fig:gr_undirected_representation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: align automatically]

Comment: Very nice, I was not aware of the subcaption package. Is it possible to also vertically center the matrix like in the variation of @heiko-oberdiek answer?

Comment: @kristoh I think you would need to calculate the heights of the other items on the line and then put the matrix into a box with the relevant height. I'm not an expert with this, by any means, though.

Comment: @kristoh There is also the `floatrow` package. However, it is extremely buggy and not likely ever to be less so. Hence, I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish all three objects to be centered vertically, you may use

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
    \usepackage{amsmath}  % draw matrices
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \newcommand{\CenterObject}[1]{\ensuremath{\vcenter{\hbox{#1}}}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Undirected graph.]{
            \CenterObject{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic1.png}}
            \label{fig:gr_undirected}
        }   
        \hfill
        \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency list.]{        
            \CenterObject{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{pic2.png}}
            \label{fig:gr_undirected_ll}
        }
        \hfill
        \large  
        \subfloat[Undirected graph adjacency matrix]{       
           $\begin{bmatrix}
           0 & 1 & 0 \\
           1 & 0 & 1 \\
           0 & 1 & 0 
         \end{bmatrix}$
            \label{fig:gr_undirected_am}
        }   
        \caption{An undirected graph and its representations.}
        \label{fig:gr_undirected_representation}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]